# How to show grid in object in threejs?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have horizontal grid Helper and polygon in scene.

Is there any way of hiding grid out of the polygon like below image?

[image]

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9rjL1sk3/1/)

```js
var camera, scene, renderer, controls, geometry, material, mesh, gridHelper, polygon;
var edges = [{
  "x": -204.87113421108512,
  "y": -150,
  "z": 350.73338884671745
}, {
  "x": -204.87113421108535,
  "y": -150,
  "z": -38.02713383973953
}, {
  "x": -83.08211641046344,
  "y": -150,
  "z": -39.62530388610881
}, {
  "x": -78.88807649109879,
  "y": -150,
  "z": -538.3155247201529
}, {
  "x": 220.63777329601388,
  "y": -150,
  "z": -535.796479191672
}, {
  "x": 220.63777329601444,
  "y": -150,
  "z": 176.94968924487634
}, {
  "x": -53.07402331399715,
  "y": -150,
  "z": 176.9496892448766
}, {
  "x": -53.07402331399726,
  "y": -150,
  "z": 350.41591086077415
}];

init();
animate();

function init() {

  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true, antialias: true });
 renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  renderer.setClearColor(0x555555, 1);
  renderer.sortObjects = true;
  
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
  scene.add(camera);
  
  camera.position.x =  1000;
  camera.position.y =  2000;
 camera.position.z =  -1000;
  
 controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );


  gridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper(1500, 30);
  gridHelper.position.y = -150;
  scene.add(gridHelper);


  var shape = new THREE.Shape();
  let firstEdge = edges[0];
  shape.moveTo(firstEdge.x, -firstEdge.z);
  const len = edges.length;
  for (let i = 1; i < len; i++) {
    shape.lineTo(edges[i].x, -edges[i].z);
  }

  shape.lineTo(firstEdge.x, -firstEdge.z);
  
  var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      color:0x00aa00,
      opacity:0.5,
      side:THREE.DoubleSide,
      transparent:true,
      depthTest:false
    });

  var polygonGeometry = new THREE.ShapeGeometry(shape);
  polygon = new THREE.Mesh(polygonGeometry, material);
  polygon.position.y = firstEdge.y;
  polygon.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2.;
  polygon.name = this.name;
  scene.add(polygon);

}

function animate() {
  controls.update();
  window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  render();

}

function render() {

  renderer.render(scene, camera);

};
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/100/three.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated!

Comment: what did you try to solve this?

Comment: @Humoyun Not actually :( nothing is coming to my mind.

Comment: Are you familiar with stencil buffers? Perhaps that would work? https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderer.stencil

Comment: [Custom shader](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/how-to-achieve-this-material-effect-gif-image/1270) comes to mind.

Comment: @DacreDenny Not I am not familiar I will check it

Comment: @WestLangley Yes it came to my mind too. I am trying to find simpler way

Comment: @imudin07 If you find one, let me know. I'm really curious about it too.

Comment: @prisoner849 Yes I will answer this post If I make it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This result I achieved with stencil buffer: https://jsfiddle.net/mmalex/g3hf4zxc/

[image: Stencil buffer clipping threejs Grid by Mesh]

```
const gl = renderer.getContext();
polygon.onBeforeRender = function () {
    gl.enable(gl.STENCIL_TEST)
    gl.stencilFunc(gl.ALWAYS, 1, 0xFF);
    gl.stencilMask(0xFF);
    gl.stencilOp(gl.KEEP, gl.KEEP, gl.INCR);
}
polygon.onAfterRender = function() {
    gl.disable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
}
polygon.renderOrder = 999;

gridHelper.onBeforeRender = function() {
    gl.enable(gl.STENCIL_TEST)
    gl.stencilMask(0x00);
    gl.stencilFunc(gl.EQUAL, 1, 0xFF);
}
gridHelper.onAfterRender = function() {
    gl.disable(gl.STENCIL_TEST)
}
gridHelper.renderOrder = 1000
```

Unfortunately I sacrificed mesh opacity, as threejs sorts opaque and transparent objects independently:

> .renderOrder : Number
>   This value allows the default rendering order of scene graph objects to be overridden although opaque and transparent objects remain sorted independently. Sorting is from lowest to highest renderOrder. Default value is 0.

https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.renderOrder

Comment: You can make the helper transparent: `gridHelper.material.transparent = true; gridHelper.material.opacity = 0.5;` Also, I would avoid changing the gl state behind the back of the renderer. The renderer maintains its own state, and changing the gl state directly will cause the two to be out-of-sync. Instead see, for example, this updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tq06bhkx/.

Comment: direct use of WebGL, it would be good if the answer will accompany detailed explanation

Comment: @Alex Khoroshylov Thanks a lot! this is exactly what I want! In my project I use renderOrder for every objects, it is totally fine

Comment: @WestLangley Should I apply stencilMask for each polygons If number of polygons is more than one?

Comment: @Alex Khoroshylov when I redraw the polygon, grid is broken

Comment: pls what you mean "broken"? could you share your jsfiddle with me?

Comment: Actually my project is making something very big. tried to make simpler sample in jsfiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/h1xa7vmz/1/

Comment: Hi @imudin07, as I mentioned before, both objects should be either opaque or transparent. In your example, please try to set: `gridHelper.material.opacity = 0.5; gridHelper.material.transparent = true;`

Comment: Hello @AlexKhoroshylov, thanks working now. https://jsfiddle.net/vahgxu1t/

Comment: I cannot really represent the issue